# Auto Layout defining constraints

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

I have two buttons on my `UIView`. I want the horizontal distance between these two buttons should, be the 20% width of the superview?

Any help about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using an empty dummy view in between the two buttons, whose width is 20 % of the width of the superview.

In code, it would look something like this:

```
// The important thing here is that the buttons are flush against the spacer
[superview addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[button1]-0-[spacer]-0-[button2]"
  options:0
  metrics:nil
  views:@{@"button1" : button1, @"button2" : button2, @"spacer" : spacer}]];
// Here, we set the width of the spacer to 20% of the super view
[superview addConstraint:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintWithItem:spacer
  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
  toItem:superview
  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
  multiplier:0.2
  constant:0]];
```

Comment: I have problem related to set auto layout constraints by IB for Portrate and landscape can you provide help related to this.Actually i want to set 10 button in single view therefor how to manage in portrate and landscape mode.

Comment: @DineshPatel It would be best to open a new question for your issue.